# Nonhomogeneous matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, matrix-decomposition

Given the vector equation
$$x' = Ax+b$$
where $x,b \in \mathbb{R}^n, x(0) = x_0, A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n},x'=\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $A$ is self-adjoint, how does the solution to such an equation change if $A$ has $0$ as an eigenvalue i.e. it is a singular matrix?

I know if your matrix can be decomposed into a diagonalizable form, that is
$$A=Q\Lambda Q^{-1}$$
the solution to the above equation is given by

$$x=Qe^{\Lambda t}(Q^{-1}x_0 + \Lambda ^{-1} Q^{-1}b)-Q\Lambda Q^{-1}b$$
Is the difference when $A$ is singular that instead of a nice diagonal matrix of eigenvalues of $\Lambda$, I will have to use the Jordan form to solve the problem? Can I use the Jordan form to find $e^{At}$?

Comment: If $A$ is self adjoint it is unitarily diagonalisable and the system reduces to $n$ one dimensional ode which are straightforward to solve. From a numerical perspective you cannot use the Jordan form.

Comment: So for a singular matrix which is  self-adjoint, I can say $A=Q\Lambda Q^{-1}$?

Comment: Yes, $Q$ can be taken to be orthogonal.